# docker sonarqube checkdependency plugin

Tags: docker, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I am trying to install the checkdepency plugin using docker Sonarqube, and PostgreSQL. I am able to get the docker SonarQube with PostgreSQL up and running, but when I try to add the check-dependency-plugin, it fails to restart the container. Is there any way to install the plugin? I am using SonarQube version 5.4 and the official PostgreSQL image from dockerhub. When I try to deploy the plugin, I am getting the error below.

```
2016.04.27 13:13:07 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1461762758226] loaded [], sites []
2016.04.27 13:13:15 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube
2016.04.27 13:13:16 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read plugin manifest from jar : /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/sonar-dependency-check-1.0.3.jar
        at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginManifest.<init>(PluginManifest.java:113) ~[sonar-update-center-common-1.13.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.PluginInfo.create(PluginInfo.java:366) ~[sonar-core-5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginRepository.loadPreInstalledPlugins(ServerPluginRepository.java:126) ~[sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginRepository.start(ServerPluginRepository.java:103) ~[sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
```

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: please format your question properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your copy of JAR file is corrupted. The release downloaded at https://github.com/stevespringett/dependency-check-sonar-plugin/releases/tag/sonar-dependency-check-1.0.3 correctly supports recent versions of SonarQube.

Comment: Hi Simon, i am using the following version of checkdependency plugin .https://bintray.com/stevespringett/owasp/dependency-check-sonar/ . and i am using sonarqube 5.4.  and when i try to read the manifest i am getting the below  $ unzip -q -c sonar-dependency-check-plugin-1.0.3.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Plugin-Description: Integrates Dependency-Check reports into SonarQube
Plugin-SourcesUrl: https://github.com/stevespringett/dependency-check-
sonar-plugin/sonar-dependency-check-plugin
Plugin-BuildDate: 2015-12-15T12:54:45-0600
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: ste

Comment: are you sure that your JAR file is not corrupted ? I can't reproduce the issue when downloading the plugin from https://github.com/stevespringett/dependency-check-sonar-plugin/releases/tag/sonar-dependency-check-1.0.3

Comment: Thanks for the quick resolution , i feel that the jar file got corrupted while downloading using curl -O and when i tried it with wget -O it worked fine . thanks

Comment: HI Simon, can we upgrade sonarqube 4.5.4 to 5.4 , with the data migration , i am now trying with postgres 9.4 ,is there any docs for this.when i try to do it shows upgrade database . how can we upgrade database.can u help with further steps please.

Comment: You should create a new question in stackoverflow (btw to help you for upgrade : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading)